# DNS Server returns SOA record instead of A record

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I have configured one DNS server which returns back the SOA record instead of A record when i query it with dig tool. Can somebody tell me what is the reason ?

```
root@pradeep-laptop:~# dig prashanth.foo

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> prashanth.foo
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 16583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;prashanth.foo.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86389   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2012072401 1800 900 604800 890

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.140.34#53(172.16.140.34)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 25 14:25:05 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```

The zone file is as follows:

```
 $TTL   300
 @  IN  SOA ns.prashanth.foo. root.prashanth.foo. (
                  2     ; Serial
                300     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
 ;

 prashanth.foo. IN  NS  ns.prashanth.foo.
 prashanth.foo.    IN      A       172.16.150.196
 ns         IN  A   172.16.150.196
 prashanth.foo.    IN      MX  10  mail.prashanth.foo.
 mail            IN      A       172.16.150.196
```

Comment: Please post the output of DIG, as well as your zone config file

Comment: It's commonly best practice to use a date formatted serial number. Instead of just `2` use `2012072500`. Update the date every day you edit the zone. Update the last two digits each time you update the zone within a single day.

Comment: Why do you obfuscate the zone? It supposed to be public anyway. You make it worse for everyone who is trying to help.

Comment: Maybe it is not obfuscated? It's a perfectly valid zone... !

Answer (score 2):

See what you get when you specify the type explicitly:

```
dig -t a prashanth.foo
```

Or

```
dig -t any prashanth.foo
```

If you're still not seeing it update the serial number and reload the zone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reloaded your zone file?

Using BIND:

`sudo rndc reload`

Answer (score 0):

Is that the exact zone file? If so, don't use spaces at the beginning of the records.
Reload named and try again after.
e.g., instead of:
..   rashanth.foo.    IN  NS  ns.prashanth.foo.
 use:
prashanth.foo.    IN  NS  ns.prashanth.foo.